# Google Vision APi Calls solutions

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-vision

Looking for a solution for ecommerce website:

Consider i have a PHP application running in  Google APP ENGINE with an "image search" feature like https://images.google.com.

Now every request that has been send through the PHP Search Query box to the VISION_API that runs analysis on the Image(Label detection or Image properties)

i.e. A client searches for a "Black T-Shirt" and similar products by uploading image of The Black T-Shirt, just like Google's image search works. The query compares the value of analyzed image with the values in DataStore.

So does that request which is made by client by uploading an image counts as a "VISION API CALL" ? 
because if it is so.
 then ***"500 thousand"*** image searches from a city will cost me  ***$748.50***  (according to price calculator ) [According to GCP VISION API PRICE ESTIMATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwZgK.png)

which is way too much costly as per month. i just need to understand, if i am wrong or is it for real but there is a solution out there to save costs anyone has come up with ?

Answer (score 0):

So far it is visible in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/), I have not seen yet implemented the functionality to search an image within an specific domain with a given image as you can do with the search engine.

However even if it was possible, indeed every API call counts as a operation, and for every operation executed you would be getting billed.

I recommend you doing a search by tags as all the other websites do, as by doing an doing an image search the process would get unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **cache** the results in database or memory.  You may reduce the calls next time.

Even you can do yourself, by using **image compare PHP libraries**.

Example:

https://github.com/nvthaovn/CompareImage